# LINQ - Deferred Execution in Subqueries

Tags: linq

My understanding is that the use of scalar or conversion functions causes immediate execution of a LINQ query. It is also my understanding that subqueries are executed upon demand of the outer query which would typically be once per element. For the following example would I be right in saying that the inner query is executed immediately? If so, as this would produce a scalar value how would this affect how the outer query operates?

```
IEnumerable<string> outerQuery = names.Where ( n => n.Length == names
                    .OrderBy(n2 => n2.Length).Select(n2 => n2.Length).First());
```

I would expect the above query to operate in a similar way as below, ie as if there wasn't a subquery.

```
int val = names.OrderBy(n2 => n2.Length).Select(n2 => n2.Length).First();

IEnumerable<string> outerQuery = names.Where ( n => n.Length == val );
```

This example was taken from Joseph and Ben Albahari's C# 4.0 in a Nutshell (Chp 8 P331/332) and my confusion stems from the accompanying diagram which appears to show that the subquery is being evaluated each time the outer query iterates through the elements of names.

Could someone clarify how LINQ works in this setup? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hi Rionmonster, the subquery would be names                  .OrderBy(n2 => n2.Length).Select(n2 => n2.Length).First()

Answer (score 1):

> For the following example would I be right in saying that the inner query is executed immediately?

No, the inner query will be executed for each item in `names` when the outer query is enumerated. If you want it to be executed only once, use the second code sample.

*EDIT: as LukeH pointed out, this is only true of Linq to Objects. Other Linq providers (Linq to SQL, Entity Framework...) might be able to optimize this automatically*

Comment: This is true of LINQ-to-Objects -- and I'm sure that's what this question is dealing with -- but it's also worth pointing out that any of the `IQueryable`-based LINQ implementations can optimise in pretty much any way they like when they translate the expression tree, so this may not be true for LINQ-to-SQL etc.

Comment: @LukeH, you're right of course... I only had Linq to Objects in mind

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Thomas, yes I was talking about a local collection (in this case of strings). I guess what I don't really understand is why it isn't evaluated immediately as it would have had it been a query by itself. Do you know why?

Comment: Because the subquery is in its own delegate, which will be executed by Where when you enumerate the query. When you write a lambda expression, you're only creating a delegate to be executed later; nothing is executed at this point. So it's behaving exactly how you specified...

Answer (score 0):

What is `names`? If it's collection (and you use LINQ to Objects) then "subquery" will be executed for each outer query item. If it's actually query object then result depends on actual `IQueryable.Provider`. For example, for LINQ to SQL you will give SQL query with scalar subquery. And in the most cases subquery actually will be executed only once.

Comment: Hi oryol, this would be a collection. If the such a query would normally be immediately evaluated, why would this be different within a subquery?

Comment: _Where_ method for LINQ to Objects is just foreach. So for each outer collection item inner delegate will be executed. It contains another LINQ query (another cycle and as it's OrderBy - even ~2 cycles).